# (FunctionReturn() - 1) fails but (-1 + FunctionReturn()) succeeds?

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer-11, operator-precedence

I have a getter/setter function that returns an absolute value. So I presumed that JavaScript would allow me to perform arithmetic with it. But it only works in a certain order...

**NOTE:** `pos.get("log", pos.get("log") + 1)` *always* returns 1 in these examples.

```
console.log("initial log: " + (-1 + pos.get("log", pos.get("log") + 1)));
// PSEUDO-CODE: -1 + (log += 1)
// RESULT: 0
```

The above code works as expected. But switch around the order and it all changes... Despite pos.get() always returning an absolute value of the same type. (Number)

```
console.log("initial log: " + (pos.get("log", pos.get("log") + 1) - 1));
// PSEUDO-CODE: (log += 1) - 1
// RESULT: 1
```

If log was equal to 0 from the beginning, the first console.log() prints 0. However, the second prints 1. I get no errors in the console whatsoever. Took me a while to figure out that the "- 1" was just being completely disregarded.

**Why?**

**EDIT: Definition of pos.get()**

```
get: function(str, val) {
        switch(str) {
            case "start": {
                if(val != undefined) {
                    start = val;
                }
                return start;
            }
            case "log": {
                if(val != undefined) {
                    log = val;
                }
                return log;
            }
            case "offset": {
                if(val != undefined) {
                    offset = val;
                }
                return offset;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `pos.get` so we can try this ourselves?

Comment: This only happens in IE11?

Comment: Updated for definition of pos.get(). I've been running it inside IE11 on my laptop. I rushed this and haven't even downloaded another browser yet.

Comment: Shouldn't the function use `this.log`, not just `log`?

Comment: `log` is within the same immediately-invoked-function closure thus gaining access without the this keyword. The `get.pos` function is actually within an object literal called `public` that the immediately-invoked-function returns. `pos` is the variable assigned to that function.

Comment: Your code looks like it's in an object prototype, that's why I thought it needs to use `this`.

Comment: Can you make an executable [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)?

Comment: What happens if you use `pos.get(...) + -1` instead of `-1 + pos.get(...)`?

Comment: Does the effect also occur if the second `console.log()` is the only `console.log()`. Right now it looks like the value of `log` is not 0 but 1, preserved from the previous `console.log()`, which would result in a `1+1-1 = 1` and therefor work as intended/written

Comment: where's log defined and initialized?

Comment: LOL Andreas is correct... I should know better than to blame the browser... Explains why I couldn't find anything searching google.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your function returns a number (e.g. float), eventually with parseFloat(). Now, I think the js parser doesn't know.

With 1 - yourFunction() the js parser suggests that the return value of your function is numeric.

Comment: If it returns a string, he'll get concatenation, but that doesn't seem to be what's happening.

Comment: A string is definitely not being returned. I'm thinking this might be a browser bug. It seems really inconsistent. Unless ecmascript defines that a function used in arithmetic is treated differently based on the order?

Comment: @thelittlegumnut It's not just order, you're changing the operator from `+` to `-`. That's why he suspected a string problem: `+` will do concatenation, while `-` will coerce the string to a number and perform subtraction.